# Replacing inflateMenu at Runtime

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I have method t change the menu of navigation drawer, I remove the line at XML file activity_main.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    />
```

so I can add the menu resource from code

```
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

But when I need to replace the menu by another resource the menu will be appended to the first one, but I need to remove the oldest
plz help me

Comment: Where is the method of changing the menu?

Comment: Are you looking for: `navigationView.getMenu().clear();` And then inflating the new menu?

Comment: yes Mohsen navigationView.getMenu().clear() will be clear first one?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for #Mohsen 
navigationView.getMenu().clear() it will do it